# R shiny: How to loop output plotly graphs

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I want to draw 20 graphs in shiny by loop and I don't want to write the output one by one. So I am thing doing a loop to output these graphs. I found a very good example in the shiny gallery which shows how to output texts. I tiried it and it worked.

Now my problem is: How can I replace the text output to plotly? I have the plotly ready(to simplify I am not showing here). What I tried is  first replace the `strong(paste0(..` line with my plotly object. Second, replace `renderUI` to `renderplotly` and replace `uiOutput` to `plotOutput`. I am getting errors `ggplotly has no applicable method for shiny.tag` which I understand that plotOutput is not compatible with tagged output. So what can I do here?

server.r:

```
    shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
     lapply(1:2, function(i) {
          output[[paste0('b', i)]] <- renderUI({
              strong(paste0('Hi, this is output B#', i)) })# to be replaced with a plotly object p
     })})
```

ui.r:

```
    fluidRow(
         lapply(1:2, function(i) {
           uiOutput(paste0('b', i))
         })

       )
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out this example Shiny app that displays a dynamic number of plots: https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415/

I adapted the above app to plot the cars dataset with ggplotly.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

shinyApp(
    ##### ui #######
    ui = fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            sliderInput("n", 
                        "Number of plots", 
                        value = 1, min = 1, max = 5)),
        fluidRow(
            uiOutput("plots"))
    ), 
    ##### server ######
    server = function(input, output) {
        data("cars")
        # define max number of plots
        max_plots <- 5
        # generate the plots
         output$plots <- renderUI({
             plot_output_list <- lapply(1:input$n, function(i) {
                 plotname <- paste0("plot", i)
                 plotlyOutput(plotname)
             })
             # convert the list to a tagList - this is necessary for the list of 
             # items to display properly
             do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
         })

         # call renderPlotly for each plot. Plots are only generated when they are 
         # visible on the web page
         for(i in 1:max_plots) {
             # Need local so that each item gets its own number. Without it, the value
             # of i in the renderPlotly() will be the same across all instances, because
             # of when the expression is evaluated
             local({
                 my_i <- i
                 plotname <- paste0("plot", my_i)

                 output[[plotname]] <- renderPlotly({
                     g <- ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
                         geom_point() +
                         labs(title = paste0("Plot ", my_i))
                     g <- ggplotly(g)
                     dev.off()
                     g
                 })
             })
         }
    }
)
```

---

Creating one plot with many subplots:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(grid)

shinyApp(
    ##### ui #######
    ui = fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            sliderInput("n", 
                        "Number of plots", 
                        value = 1, min = 1, max = 5)),
        fluidRow(
            plotlyOutput("plots")
        )
    ), 
    ##### server ######
    server = function(input, output) {
        data("cars")
        # define max number of plots
        max_plots <- 5
        # generate the plots
        output$plots <- renderPlotly({
            plot_list <- lapply(1:input$n, function(i) {
                g <- ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
                    geom_point() +
                    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(3, 1, 1, 1), "lines"))
                ggplotly(g)
            })
            p <- subplot(plot_list[1:input$n], shareX = TRUE, shareY = TRUE) %>%
                layout(title = "Car Plots")
            dev.off()
            p
        })
    }
)
```

Comment: What should I do with the ui.r?

Comment: The ui is included in the code above. I added comments to make each section clearer. You could separate the code into a ui.R and server.R if you'd like.

Comment: Oh, Sorry somehow I missed the ui part at the beginning. Yes, i revised my code according to your example and now it is working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! I'm happy to help

Comment: I should have raised a different question but I was wondering if by any chance you know how to apply split layout to `uioutput`? I tried to add a `splitlayout` (including `cellwidths(50%,50%)`, page margin etc)on top of `uioutput`. Everything worked except for the `cellwidths`, the plot is showing in a new row instead of on the right side.

Comment: It sounds like you want to create one plot with many subplots instead of dynamically creating many plots. I've edited the answer to add this as an option.

Comment: Hi, How to edit the title of each subplots? @blondeclover

Comment: Many years later - +1 for giving a fully working example, that is not at all what I'm looking for, but helps me know that ggplotly WILL work on with Shiny on Windows, and that it's my own mumbo-jumbo code that's irritating me.  Thanks.